# Catalina 10.15.5 Bluetooth (Keyboard) Connection Not Working

Tags: catalina, bluetooth, software-update

- MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)
- Catalina 10.15.5 update (***last night when I went to bed***)
- Bluetooth: 7.0.5f6
- Firmware Version: v150 c9318 (from About Thus Mac; System
  Report;Hardware; Bluetooth).

This morning, 2009  Wireless Keyboard not connecting, not even seen.

Also posted with another user at Apple Communities [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251422255?page=1).

Comment: What have you already tried to fix this?  Does the keyboard connect to any other device?  Can the MBA connect to any other BT device?  Have you performed the usual troubleshooting steps of reboot and/or [reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)?

Comment: Does your keyboard work in Safe Mode? You can get there by holding down Shift while rebooting your Mac.

Comment: The same vintage mouse still works fine. Reboot yes, always. I always hesitate to reset unless I know it will likely work. It’s like when Apple says reinstall OS. Really? Safe boot is easy. Will  try. Hoping to see others with the issue (or not) to at least know how common it is. Rare enough to have that combo, a 2009 wireless keyboard w/ AA batteries, used with a Mac with the latest OS. 

Would be good to hear from anyone with that keyboard and a Mac with 10.15.5 to know if they are having a problem or not, before taking a deep dive.

Comment: Also the keyboard works fine with iPad with iOS 13.5.

Answer (score 0):

> What have you already tried to fix this? Does the keyboard connect to any other device? Can the MBA connect to any other BT device? Have you performed the usual troubleshooting steps of reboot and/or reset SMC? – fsb Jun 3 at 16:23

**Thanks [fsb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/88313/fsb) the SMC reset did the trick.**

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with Catalina. Fixed it with instructions in the link below.

https://michaelkummer.com/tech/mac-bluetooth-issues/

Unfortunately, with High Sierra (even with Bluetooth dongle) no fix found so far.

The very first thing you can do is to press Alt+Shift and at the same time click on your Bluetooth icon in menu bar to get further options. Click on Debug and Reset the Bluetooth module.

If you still have issues, then you can try to delete then following files in `~/Library/Preferences` folder:

```
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist – Magic Trackpad
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist – Magic Mouse
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist – wired USB mouse
com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist
com.apple.preference.trackpad.plist
```

In addition, be aware no fix works on High Sierra. As for Catalina, I have to confess the fix is not stable enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).